# Javascript - toggle xp system (mongodb and discord.js with discord-xp api)

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I have made discord.js **XP system** with **discord-xp** and **mongodb**, I wanted to make the XP system toggleable but I can't really do it, I would appreciate your help.
When I toggle off the command, it does its thing in database, but still gives me XP when messaging.
I doubt that the problem is in ToggleXP.js, I think the problem is in index.js file
**ToggleXP.js:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const toggleLevels = require('../Schema/level-toggle-schema')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (args[0] === 'off' || args[0] === 'disable' || args[0] === 'disabled') {
    const settings = await toggleLevels.findOne({

      guildID: message.guild.id,

    }, async (err, guild) => {
      if (err) console.error(err)

      if (!guild) {

        const newGuild = new toggleLevels({
          guildID: message.guild.id,
          enabled: 'true'
        })

        newGuild.save()
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));

      }
      if (guild) {
        const newGuild = new toggleLevels({
          guildID: message.guild.id,
          enabled: 'false'
        })

        newGuild.save()
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      }
    });
    return message.reply(`XP system has been disabled!`);
  }



  if (args[0] === 'on' || args[0] === 'enable' || args[0] === 'enabled') {
    const settings = await toggleLevels.findOne({

      guildID: message.guild.id,

    }, async (err, guild) => {
      if (err) console.error(err)

      if (!guild) {

        const newGuild = new toggleLevels({
          guildID: message.guild.id,
          enabled: 'true'
        })

        newGuild.save()
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));

      }
      if (guild) {
        const newGuild = new toggleLevels({
          guildID: message.guild.id,
          enabled: 'true'
        })

        newGuild.save()
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      }
    })
    return message.reply(`XP system has been enabled!`);
  }
  console.log(`${message.author.tag} (${message.author.id}) used 'togglexp' command`)
}
module.exports.config = {
  name: 'togglexp',
  aliases: ['togglelevels']
}
```

**index.js message event:**

```
if (!message.content.startsWith(bot.prefix)) {
    toggleLevels.findOne({
    guildID: message.guild.id
  }, async (err, guild) => {
    if (!guild) {
    let randomXp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 1
    const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomXp);
    if (hasLeveledUp) {
      const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
      message.channel.send(`Congrats <@${message.author.id}>, You are now Level ${user.level}. Keep it going!`)
    }
    }
    if (guild.enabled) {
    let randomXp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 1
    const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomXp);
    if (hasLeveledUp) {
      const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
      message.channel.send(`Congrats <@${message.author.id}>, You are now Level ${user.level}. Keep it going!`)
    }
    }
    })

    }
```

**level-toggle-schema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const config = mongoose.Schema({
    guildID: String,
    enabled: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('level-toggle', config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the message event inside with

```js
const toggleLvl = await toggleLevels.findOne({
    guildID: message.guild.id
});
if (!toggleLvl) {
    let randomXp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 1
    const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomXp);
    if (hasLeveledUp) {
        const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
        message.channel.send(`Congrats <@${message.author.id}>, You are now Level ${user.level}. Keep it going!`)
    }
}
if (toggleLvl.enabled) {
    let randomXp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 1
    const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomXp);
    if (hasLeveledUp) {
        const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
        message.channel.send(`Congrats <@${message.author.id}>, You are now Level ${user.level}. Keep it going!`)
    }
}
```

Comment: You also can simplify both statements with a ||